# How to "Cover up blank space after groupbox visibility is collapsed"

Tags: c#, xaml

I´m editing user control. This user control contains timeline. My current problem is, when i set `Visibility.Collapsed` on Groupbox, it disapear, which is fine. But, there is blank space after it and I want datagrid, which is under this groupbox to get full size and cover up the blank space from groupbox.

This is the actual code I get:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>       
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GroupBox x:Name="gbLoadData" Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding Path=gbBasicInfoVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Základní informace" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="85*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Řidič"  FontSize="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0"  FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="SPZ" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" />
                <TextBox Margin="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Driver,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBox Margin="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding SPZ,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>           

        <GroupBox x:Name="gbdLoadData" Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxStyle}" Visibility="{Binding Path=gbExportVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Export" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
           <Button  x:Name="btnExportExcel"  Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding ExportToExcelCmd}">
               <StackPanel>
                   <Image Source="/Z05.MES.WPF.WeighingSystem;Component/Resources/excel.png" Height="23" Width="32" />
               </StackPanel>
           </Button>
       </GroupBox>        
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource Z05DataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionTimeLineForRecord,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Popis"   MinWidth="150" FontSize="16"  Header="Popis" Width="10*"  Binding="{Binding ActionDescriptionText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ActionDescriptionText}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DateAndTime" FontSize="16" Width="150" MaxWidth="150" Header="Čas" Binding="{Binding DateTimeStamp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellCenterStyle}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Parametry" MinWidth="150" FontSize="16" Header="Parametry" Width="5*" Binding="{Binding ParametersFlat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterGridHeaderStyle}" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ParametersFlat}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <interactivity:InteractionTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest}" IsCentered="True" IsModal="True" Style="{StaticResource InteractionTrigger}">
    </interactivity:InteractionTrigger>

    <interactivity:InteractionTrigger  SourceObject="{Binding BoxWithMessageRequest}" IsCentered="True" IsModal="False" Style="{StaticResource InteractionTrigger}">
        <interactivity:InteractionTrigger.InteractionWindow>
            <boxMessage:DWBoxWithMessage/>
        </interactivity:InteractionTrigger.InteractionWindow>
    </interactivity:InteractionTrigger>

</Grid>
```

I just want Datagrid to get in full size, when i set groupboxes to `Visibility.Collapsed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `Heigth` and `Width` of the Rows and Columns to `auto` instead of concrete values, like:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>       
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid>
    ...
</Grid>
```

then the grid can rearange its content if it has nothing to display in a Row or Column.